# Filter a set in Clojure clojure.set/select vs. clojure.core/filter

Tags: clojure

I would like to filter a set, something like:

```
(filter-set even? #{1 2 3 4 5})
; => #{2 4}
```

If I use `clojure.core/filter` I get a seq which is not a set:

```
(filter even? #{1 2 3 4 5})
; => (2 4)
```

So the best I came with is:

```
(set (filter even? #{1 2 3 4 5}))
```

But I don't like it, doesn't look optimal to go from set to list back to set. What would be the Clojurian way for this ?

**UPDATE**

I did the following to compare @A.Webb and @Beyamor approaches. Interestingly, both have almost identical performance, but `clojure.set/select` is slightly better.

```
(defn set-bench []
  (let [big-set (set (take 1000000 (iterate (fn [x] (int (rand 1000000000))) 1)))]
    (time (set (filter even? big-set))) ; "Elapsed time: 422.989 msecs"
    (time (clojure.set/select even? big-set))) ; "Elapsed time: 345.287 msecs"
    nil) ; don't break my REPL !
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the performance of `clojure.set/select` should be about the same as `(set (filter ... ))`. Try timing it for a large set. Keep in mind that (1) `filter` does not actually create the whole list as it is lazy and that (2) Clojure is all about immutable data structures, so you have to start letting go of the natural aversion to creating new structures.

Comment: @A.Webb interesting, see my update in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[clojure.set](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.set-api.html) is a handy API for common set operations.

In this case, [clojure.set/select](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.set-api.html#clojure.set/select) is a set-specific filter. It works by dissociating elements which don't meet the predicate from the given set.

```
(require 'clojure.set)

(clojure.set/select even? #{1 2 3 4 5})
; => #{2 4}
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that in the clojure.set doc. Thanks !